# How to make bootstrap-vue checkbox-group single selection

Tags: checkbox, bootstrap-vue

Using checkboxes of bootstrap-vue at
 https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-checkbox/#form-checkbox-inputs
 I need to use Grouped switch style checkboxes, like  https://prnt.sc/qzmmo7
 But I need to select only 1 option and I did not find if there is such options?
 I tried :

```
         <b-form-checkbox-group
                v-model="selected"
                :options="options"
                switches
                :multiple="false"
        ></b-form-checkbox-group>
```

but it did not help.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for radio buttons that are switch styled? A switch implies that it can be either enabled/disabled by clicking it again, which a radio input doesn't support (unlike a checkbox), which is why Bootstrap v4 CSS only supports switch styling on checkboxes. Trying to force checkboxes to work like radio buttons would be confusing to screen reader users.